# MYSQL - Get all records that have more than 1 record for the same id

Tags: mysql, sql

I apologize in advanced if I am not explaining this correctly. I can barely explain it in english terms, let alone in a mysql query.

I am trying to get the list of `response_set_ids` that have more than 1 record for a `question_id`.

This is an example of my data:

```
+----+-----------------+-------------+-----------+
| id | response_set_id | question_id | answer_id |
+----+-----------------+-------------+-----------+
|  1 |              10 |           1 |         4 |
|  2 |              10 |           2 |         5 |
|  3 |              10 |           3 |         6 |
|  4 |              10 |           3 |         7 |
|  5 |              11 |           1 |         8 |
|  6 |              11 |           2 |         9 |
|  7 |              11 |           3 |        10 |
+----+-----------------+-------------+-----------+
```

I would like to have a query that would return me a list response_set_ids, and in this particular example, I would expect to get returned `10` because that response_set has `question_id -> 3` showing up more than once.

Please let me know if you need any further information to help me.

I have tried this:
`select response_set_id, count(question_id) from responses group by response_set_id;`

But that only gives me the counts of questions per response_set.

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Please see answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method doesn't use a subquery:

```
SELECT DISTINCT response_set_id
FROM responses
GROUP BY response_set_id, question_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

This is one of the very, very few instances where `select distinct` is used (appropriately) with `group by`.

Comment: Even better! Works beautifully. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct response_set_id from (
    select  response_set_id , question_id  
    from 
    responses
    group by 
    response_set_id, question_id
    having count(*)>1) a
```

Comment: Thank you! but this also did not work :(
It returned nothing, when it should have returned at least 1 record. I'm going to give it a think and get back to you if I figure out why that is not working.

Comment: sorry remove id - should work now - see updated above

Comment: anytime - let me know if you need help with anything else

Answer (score 0):

I believe this question has been asked before but I cannot add comments at my current rep:

```
SELECT DISTINCT response_set_id
FROM responses
GROUP BY question_id
HAVING COUNT(question_id) > 1
```

Comment: Thousands of times Im sure

Comment: This did not work. It returned me records that do not match what I am trying to do. And my apologies if this has been asked thousands of times, I cannot find something that works.

I need to find the response_set_id which has the same question_id more than once.

Question_id can be used in other response_set_ids.