# mysql get all cards record that have last 7 failed transactions

Tags: mysql

i have three table
`cards (id,...)` 
`order_cards (card_id, order_id....)`
`transactions (order_card_id, status, ....)`

i want to get all cards that had last 7 transactions failed

i am trying something like that

```
select  cards.*,
(
select sum(case tmp1.status when 'fail' then 1 else 0 end) from  
(select transactions.status from order_cards
left join transactions on transactions.order_card_id = order_cards.id
where order_cards.card_id = cards.id
order by transactions.id desc limit 7
) as tmp1
) as total_fail
from cards

group by cards.id
having total_fail > 5
```

getting this error

```
 Unknown column 'cards.id' in 'where clause'
```

issue with above query is parent id not working in level 2 subquery.
tried to use having clause with count but its not working with limit
any suggestion thanks

already tried

[Use column of parent query in subquery of a subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37166457/use-column-of-parent-query-in-subquery-of-a-subquery)

[MYSQL - Get all records that have more than 1 record for the same id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50591283/mysql-get-all-records-that-have-more-than-1-record-for-the-same-id)

Comment: Can you describe the exact error you are getting?

Comment: @JerryM. i have updated query can you take a look now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the `parent-id`s can NOT be used in the derived table in FROM clause, but are still accessible in the WHERE clause and SELECT list in the Sub-Sub-query. So in your case, you can find the 8th latest transaction.id (`LIMIT 7,1`) of the card_id and then `SUM()` based on that transaction.id: (note when there are less than 8 transactions in the same card_id, `LIMIT 7,1` will return NULL, in such case, all transactions should be counted, and thus below: `t1.id > IFNULL((...), 0)`):

```
SELECT  c.*
,   IFNULL((
      SELECT sum(t1.status = 'fail') 
      FROM order_cards o1
      JOIN transactions t1 on t1.order_card_id = o1.id
      WHERE o1.card_id = c.id
      AND t1.id > IFNULL((
          SELECT t2.id 
          FROM order_cards o2
          JOIN transactions t2 on t2.order_card_id = o2.id
          WHERE o2.card_id = c.id
          ORDER BY t2.id DESC 
          LIMIT 7,1
      ), 0)
    ), 0) as total_fail
FROM cards c
HAVING total_fail > 5
```

I tested a similar SQL on the database of my own server which works fine, and the same method might apply to your case.

Comment: i need to count total fail from last 7 transactions. above query will count fail from all transactions

Comment: I modified the SQL so it runs SUM() based on the transaction_id calculated by a sub-query. let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

`Select c.*,  SUM(t.status = 'FAILED') AS failed_txns
 from cards c, order_cards oc, transactions t
where t.status='FAILED'
and oc.order_id = t.order_card_id
and c.id = oc.card_id
group by c.id
having failed_txns >= 7`

Comment: this is not working is not working in my case. i need to check last 7 transaction not 7 failed transactions

Comment: You mean to say that you need to check only the last 7 transactions and if all 7 txnx failed are of same card id they need to be displayed? Ex - There are 3 types of cards A, B and C and there were 16 txns in total. Of the last 7 txns, if A failed 2 times, B failed 3 times and C failed 2 times (all 7 txns failed but for different cards), what do you intend to see in out put A = 2, B =3 and C =2 or do you want to see NONE as neither A, B or C failed 7 consecutive times.

Comment: yes i have to check last 7 transaction of card A. if all failed then it will be listed.
same for Card B and C